# Text selection on terminal with Mac

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, macos-mojave

I've just been given a MacBook (Mojave) by my employer and I'm really struggling to get to grips with the terminal.  *I've been a Linux user for years and am always in the terminal.*

I've tried a number of different terminals; Terminal, ITerm2 and Alacritty and so far I've not been able to work out how to do the most basic text selection operations without having to reach for the mouse.

With ITerm2 I have actually managed to get word selection working but not selecting from the cursor to the start/end of line or cutting of the selection.

I've seen on the Internet some other people (but surprisingly few) asking similar questions and the answer they got was that it's just not possible.  I'm struggling to accept that this can be the case - and the fact that not many people seem to be screaming out about this is making me wonder if the people asking this question (including me) are somehow misconfigured.

Text selection operations work fine for me outside of the terminal, e.g. in a text editor.

Can anyone help?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228162/text-selection-in-terminal-without-mouse-moving-cursor-using-arrow-keys

Comment: When I moved from Linux to macOS, I had the initial discomfort. After a while, I realize I am just as productive using the Trackpad. To answer your question, you can use the Find feature and assign keyboard shortcut, or use Copy mode ala vi editing mode https://superuser.com/questions/93573/select-text-in-iterm-using-keyboard

Comment: Thanks both - that's a shame

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal - Place the cursor at one of of the text you want to copy, then click on the track pad and hold, then drag to the other end you want to copy. It will highlight the text, let go of the mouse pad when at the end. Then press the "command" + "C" key to copy, "command" + V to paste somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I really want to be able to do this without touching a mouse/trackpad.